# Increment and decrement number on click with DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to display Increment and decrement number on click on a `+` and a `-`. How do I do it? Thank you:)

Here is my code -->

```js
var minutes = 25,
    seconds = 0,
    isPaused = true,
    timerId = 0,
    remainingTime,
    countdownHandle,
    plus = document.getElementByClassName('plus');
    show = document.getElementByClassName('value');


function plus(){
  $('.plus').on('click', function(){
    minutes++;
    $('.value').html(minutes);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-wrapper" id="session">
    <div class="control-header">SESSION LENGTH</div>
        <div class="control">
          <div class="plus">+</div>
          <div class="value">25</div>
          <div class="minus">-</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed it to `plus = $('plus')` `show = $('value')` but it still does not work. Is my function okay?

Comment: Please see my answer. You have multiple issues

Comment: It would be `plus = $('.plus')` - but there is no need to store it where you do - it would likely not exist yet unless your script is at the end of the page

Answer (score 1):

1. getElementByClassName is plural so you need getElementsByClassName()[0] - but actually do not need it at all since you have jQuery. If you MUST use DOM use `document.querySelector(".plus")` but you do not currently use the vars `plus` or `show` at all in your code so far
2. You need to use `$function() {... });` instead of a function you do not call. It executes when the page has loaded and your elements exist
3. `show` was not inside the var since you had semicolon on one of the previous lines

```js
var minutes = 25,
    seconds = 0,
    isPaused = true,
    timerId = 0,
    remainingTime,
    countdownHandle;


$(function() { // on page load
  $('.plus').on('click', function(){
    minutes++;
    $('.value').html(minutes);
  });
  $('.minus').on('click', function(){
    minutes--;
    $('.value').html(minutes);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-wrapper" id="session">
    <div class="control-header">SESSION LENGTH</div>
        <div class="control">
          <div class="plus">+</div>
          <div class="value">25</div>
          <div class="minus">-</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do I have to wrapped `function` with `()`? What does it mean?

Comment: It is executing when the page loads. It is similar to the DOM `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as little as possible to make it work.

```js
var minutes = 25,
    seconds = 0,
    isPaused = true,
    timerId = 0,
    remainingTime,
    countdownHandle,
    plus = document.querySelector('.plus'),
    show = document.querySelector('.value');



  $('.plus').on('click', function() {
    minutes++;
    $('.value').html(minutes);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-wrapper" id="session">
    <div class="control-header">SESSION LENGTH</div>
        <div class="control">
          <button class="plus">+</button>
          <div class="value">25</div>
          <button class="minus">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe I already answered this - and wrapped it $(function() {}) so it exists when called

Comment: I actually did this code before I posted it but it did not work, lol

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('.plus').click(function(){
  $('.value').html(parseInt($('.value').text()) + 1);
});

$('.minus').click(function(){
  $('.value').html(parseInt($('.value').text()) - 1);
});
```

```css
.plus, .minus {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-wrapper" id="session">
  <div class="control-header">SESSION LENGTH</div>
  <div class="control">
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <div class="value">25</div>
    <div class="minus">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery its simple

```js
$('.plus').click(function() {
    $('#value').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});

$('.minus').click(function() {
    $('#value').html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
});
```

```css
.control .plus {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.control .minus {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-wrapper" id="session">
  <div class="control-header">SESSION LENGTH</div>
  <div class="control">
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <div id="value">25</div>
    <div class="minus">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```